# Recursively find subdirectories and files

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I want to retrieve all the files, directories and subdirectories contained within a given path, recursively. But I have a problem when my code reaches the second level (a directory within a directory): instead of opening the inner directory to search its contents, it throws an error. Here is what I have done:

```
void getFile(char *path)
{

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir(path)) != NULL) {
    /* print all the files and directories within directory */
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      if((strcmp(ent->d_name,"..") != 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name,".") != 0)){

      printf ("%s", ent->d_name);

      if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR){

      printf("/\n");
      getFile(ent->d_name);
      }
      else{

      printf("\n");
      }
      }   // end of if condition
    }     // end of while loop
    closedir (dir);

}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing, can you include that in your post?

Comment: Note that not all file systems support the `d_type` member.  If the type is `D_UNKNOWN`, you need to call [`stat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) on the directory entry to determine if it's a subdirectory or other kind of file.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ftw(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw) library function to recursively walk a file tree. It is quite standard.

You may also look into `nftw` and the [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) source [code for it](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/misc/nftw.c). It is quite readable.

Comment: i need to make custom . lab project

Answer (score 4):

When you recursively call `getFile` you only call it with the only the name of the directory you just read. It's *not* the full path, which is what you need. You have to manage that yourself.

---

Something like this:

```
if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
{
    if ((strlen(path) + strlen(ent->d_name) + 1) > PATH_MAX)
    {
        printf("Path to long\n");
        return;
    }

    char fullpath[PATH_MAX + 1];

    strcpy(fullpath, path);
    strcat(fullpath, "/");
    strcat(fullpath, ent->d_name); // corrected

    getFile(fullpath);
}
```

Comment: please help me out with it how can i provide the full path