# Recursively searching a directory, compilation errors that I do not understand

Tags: c, file, search, recursion

I need to recursively search a UNC path for a given filename (`request`), I've successfully connected to the path, and found an answer on searching  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107567/recursively-find-subdirectories-and-files), however, when I compile my program I get the following errors:

```
find-util.c: In function ‘char* search_utils(const char*, int, bool)’:
find-util.c:51:16: error: ‘struct dirent’ has no member named ‘d_type’
       if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
                ^
find-util.c:51:26: error: ‘DT_DIR’ was not declared in this scope
       if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
                          ^
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using the `mingw` compiler to cross compile to be able to run on Windows 7. Am I missing a library? Or is there something else going on that I'm not seeing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *search_utils(const char *request, int depth, bool verbose)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;

    puts("Connecting to mgtutils..");

    if ((dir = opendir(MG_PATH)) != NULL)
    {
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (verbose == true)
            {
                printf("Searching%s for %s\n", ent->d_name, request);
            }
            if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
            {
                if ((strlen(MG_PATH) + strlen(ent->d_name) + 1) > PATH_MAX)
                {
                    puts("Path to long, cannot");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this possible explanation in online linux man page [READDIR(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html):

> The only fields in the dirent structure that are mandated by POSIX.1
>   are d_name and d_ino.  The other fields are unstandardized, and not
>   present on all systems; see NOTES below for some further details.

Thus, please, edit your question and state what OS/platform and compiler you are using.

You may also have a look into `dirent.h`.

I did this on cygwin where `/usr/include/dirent.h` includes `sys/dirent.h`. In `/usr/include/sys/dirent.h`, I found multiple flavors of `struct dirent` and, yes, in this case a `d_type` component was existing. (So you're probably not on cygwin...)

So, if `struct dirent` does not provide `d_type` in your case, what else you could use? How about [`stat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)...

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 16.04, mingw compiler to cross compile into Windows 7

Comment: Hmm. `readdir()` does not exist on Windows. win32 API instead provides `FindFirst()`/`FindNext()`. However, mingw may wrap this somehow into Posix like `readdir()`. (I don't know.) Thus, the bottom part of my answer may lead you into the right direction...

Comment: Thinking twice I'm concerned what headers are used for cross compile. Reading carefully the command line calls of `gcc` (especially include directories after `-I` arguments) should give a hint. I never did this by myself but I know somebody who cross-compiled libraries for Windows out of Linux/mingw. If you get stuck I could ask him...